# How to shade a portion of the background of ChartJS bubble chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I managed to figure out how to enhance the solutions I've found here in stackoverflow for adding vertical and horizontal lines to a line chart in ChartJS v2+ to apply to a bubble chart [ChartJS Bubble w/Lines](http://jsfiddle.net/b2jt3a84/1/) (I advise skipping to my **Update** at the end for a better approach)

```
 var originalBubbleDraw = Chart.controllers.bubble.prototype.draw;
  Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.bubble.prototype, {
    draw: function() {
      originalBubbleDraw.apply(this, arguments);

      var chart = this.chart;
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      var xvalue = chart.config.data.queryLimits['x'];
      var yvalue = chart.config.data.queryLimits['y'];
      var xcolor = chart.config.data.queryLimits['xcolor'];
      var ycolor = chart.config.data.queryLimits['ycolor'];
      var lineThickness = 3;

      function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,color) {
        console.log("color="+color+", x1="+x1+", x2="+x2+", y1="+y1+", y2="+y2);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineWidth=lineThickness;
        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
      }

      // draw vertical line
      if (xvalue) {
        x1 = xaxis.getPixelForValue(xvalue);
        x2 = xaxis.getPixelForValue(xvalue);
        y1 = yaxis.top;
        y2 = yaxis.bottom;
        drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,xcolor);
      }

      // draw horizontal line
      if (yvalue) {
        x1 = xaxis.left;
        x2 = xaxis.right;
        y1 = yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue);
        y2 = yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue);
        drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,ycolor);
      }
    }
  });

var config = {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: {
    queryLimits: {x: 42, y: 21, xcolor: '#00FF00', ycolor: '#0000ff'},
    datasets: [
      {
          label: '',
          data: [
              {x: 20, y: 30, r: 15},
              {x: 40, y: 10, r: 10},
              {x: 100, y: 15, r: 10},
              {x: 50, y: 22, r: 5},
              {x: 80, y: 26, r: 3},
              {x: 63, y: 28, r: 10},
              {x: 71, y: 18, r: 12}
          ],
          backgroundColor:"#FF6384",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "#FF6384",
      }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

I need to take this one step further and shade the area/background of the chart on one side of vertical line and above or below the horizontal line a different color (like a light gray or something subtle).

I am not sure if the approach is to try to change a portion of the background or to add rectangles sized and positioned to simulate the background shading.

Ideas?

Here is an example mockup of the goal:

[image: Bubble/Scatter With Horizontal & Vertical Lines & Shaded Area]

**Update**

For what it is worth for those viewing this in the future, I ended up discovering a better way to approach both the drawing of lines and rectangles by using the annotation plugin for chartjs found here https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation. It is far easier to work with and doesn't have the consequence of firing the code to draw the lines and rectangles more than necessary. Also I ended up able to use another plugin https://github.com/compwright/chartjs-plugin-draggable for dragging annotations created from that first plugin. I am leaving the accepted answer as-is because it does answer the question I had from the context of how to solve the rectangle shaded area following the original extension approach, however I recommend the plugin approach vs that now after learning more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did with your `queryLimits` attribute, you can do the same way an attribute that fills the portion you want.

By adding the following attribute to your chart dataset :

```js
fillBackground: {
    // In this porperty, add the string portion you want to fill
    // Inputs are : "tr" for top-right
    //              "tl" for top-left 
    //              "br" for bottom-right 
    //              "bl" for bottom-left 
    pos: ["tr", "bl", "br"],

    // A single color will be used in all the portions
    // But you can also set an array of colors which must have the same length as the pos
    // i.e color: ["rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", "rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3)", "rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5)"]
    color: "rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.15)"
}
```

Then adding the following piece of code in your `draw()` function :

```js
function drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
    ctx.restore();
}

// Checks if you have the attribute in your dataset
if (chart.config.data.fillBackground) {

    // Make sure you have portions in your chart
    if (!xvalue || !yvalue) return;

    var pos = chart.config.data.fillBackground.pos;
    var color = chart.config.data.fillBackground.color;

    // For every position in your array ..
    for (p in pos) {

        // Based on the string code, fills the right portion
        switch (pos[p]) {
            case "tl":
                drawRect(xaxis.left, yaxis.top, xaxis.getPixelForValue(xvalue) - lineThickness / 2 - xaxis.left, yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue) - lineThickness / 2 - yaxis.top, (Array.isArray(color)) ? color[p] : color);
                break;
            case "tr":
                drawRect(xaxis.getPixelForValue(xvalue) + lineThickness / 2, yaxis.top, xaxis.right, yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue) - lineThickness / 2 - yaxis.top, (Array.isArray(color)) ? color[p] : color);
                break;
            case "bl":
                drawRect(xaxis.left, yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue) + lineThickness / 2, xaxis.getPixelForValue(xvalue) - lineThickness / 2 - xaxis.left, yaxis.bottom - (yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue) + lineThickness / 2), (Array.isArray(color)) ? color[p] : color);
                break
            case "br":
                drawRect(xaxis.getPixelForValue(xvalue) + lineThickness / 2, yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue) + lineThickness / 2, xaxis.right, yaxis.bottom - (yaxis.getPixelForValue(yvalue) + lineThickness / 2), (Array.isArray(color)) ? color[p] : color);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This should solve your problem.

You can check your example working with these functions in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2jt3a84/4/), and here is the result :

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed answer and flexible solution. Are these rectangles by default sitting over top of the points and lines in the chart or underneath? Is there a z-dimension that blocks objects underneath? I ask because the next task will be to build some interaction handling so the lines can be moved (shading would follow line movement) and the points can be clicked to navigate elsewhere.

Comment: @Streamline Unfortunately, there's no built-in z property in canvas. The same problem applies to Chart.js. I don't know how you could make it, I'd be glad to know if you happen to find it though.

Comment: For what it is worth, I ended up discovering a better way to approach both the drawing of lines and rectangles by using the annotation plugin for chartjs found here https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation. It is far easier to work with and doesn't have the consequence of firing the code to draw the lines and rectangles more than necessary. Also I ended up able to use another plugin for dragging annotations created from that first plugin. I will update the original post as well for future folks.

Comment: @Streamline Yeah plugins are one of the best things of Chart.js. I should have thought about it instead of doing the same as how you did with your lines. I could try to provide a fully working plugin that adds the background when you'll do the lines if you want